# PHP Get Form issue

Tags: php, forms, post, get, show

I have the following quote:

```
<form class="searchform" name="search" id="search" action="<?php echo base_url();?>video/search" method="get" >
                <input type="text" name="search_key" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search video';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search video') {this.value = '';}" value="<?php if(isset($search_key))echo $search_key;else echo 'Search video';?>" class="searchfield" onKeyPress="return submitenter(this,event)">
        </form>
```

the page url looks like this after search - for example:

```
mypage.com/video/search?search_key=blabla
```

and the code that I'm using to show it off is:

```
<?php echo $_GET["search_key"]; ?>
```

but it's not working and I do not understand why.

I can not make -blabla- show up in the page.

Comment: Is `mypage.com/video/search` a php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `action` in the `form` tag , should be a PHP file like `myphp.php` , then you can use `$_GET[`["search_key'];`at`myphp.php` for getting it. for example

```
action="<?php echo base_url();?>video/search/myphp.php"
```

then URL should like `mypage.com/video/search/myphp.php?search_key=blabla`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look and see if there is any values at all in the `$_GET` super global by using `var_dump($_GET)` which will dump a not-so-pretty string of the object to the screen.

Also have a try the `$_REQUEST` and `$GLOBALS` variables and see if they have any values by doing the same as above.

If these do not show your value, you may need to force set the `enctype` of the Form so PHP knows that it can take the Query String (the text from the `?` onwards) or the POST data into the super globals. The `enctype` you will want to use is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is [meant to be the default value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) but just in case, set it.

With it set, your form will look like

```
<form class="searchform" name="search" id="search" action="<?php echo base_url();?>video/search" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="text" name="search_key" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search video';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search video') {this.value = '';}" value="<?php if(isset($search_key))echo $search_key;else echo 'Search video';?>" class="searchfield" onKeyPress="return submitenter(this,event)" />
</form>
```

[Super Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Also just in case you missed it, your `input` tag needs a `/` before closing `>`, like `/>` otherwise it isn't valid markup.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL `/search?search_key=blabla` is shown, try to use `$_POST` and catch with `print_r($_POST)`, because the default form method on CI is using post.

Answer (score 0):

for getting get value from query string you have to set true your query string.

go to 
1) application/config/config.php
2) set query string option true

Ex.  $config['enable_query_strings'] = true;

than you can get $_GET["search_key"]

other wise send value like

```
mypage.com/video/search/blabla
```

you will get "blabla" in first perameter of search function in cideo controller.